# Duplicated instance of view controller in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, ios10

I have 2 story boards in my application: LoginController and MainController, each of them set with its initial view controller.

When the app finishes launching, I want to directly display the TabBarController to skip the login screen:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Fabric.with([Twitter.self])

    // Check if the user is already logged in
    let existingUserSessions = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.existingUserSessions()
    let isUserLoggedIn = !existingUserSessions.isEmpty

    // If the user is already logged in the TabBarController is instantiated and set
    if isUserLoggedIn {
        let tabBarController = TabBarController.storyboardInstance()
        self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    }

    return true
}
```

This is my info.plist file:
[image: info.plist]

And this is my TabBarController class:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

static func storyboardInstance() -> TabBarController? {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TabBarController", bundle: nil)
    return storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as?
    TabBarController
}

}
```

The problem is that, in the case the user is already logged in, if I inspect the memory graph I see that there are 2 instances of TabBarController, Why?

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned the build and it didn't happen anymore.. damn